# Is there an Android ROM flashing utility available for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, android, broadcom

Is there any Utility that can be used in Ubuntu 14.04 to flash a ROM or a custom recovery to an android? I am interested in flashing the stock ROM and CWM recovery to a Broadcom chip based android mobile running on android 4.4.2 version.

Comment: I meant, any specific application that can be used without going to the command line prompt e.g, SP Flashtool we use in Windows7 for flashing to a MTK android device.

Answer (score 5):

The `adb` and `fastboot` tools that come with the Android SDK are in the repository:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

To flash the images, connect the device to the machine, enable USB debugging and reboot the device into the bootloader by running `adb reboot bootloader`.

Then flash the images using `fastboot`. For example, to flash a custom recovery partition:

```
fastboot flash recovery custom-recovery.img
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. *But one does not simply "flash a ROM" from USB*, but parts or more specifically images. These will be **system.img**, **recovery.img** and so on.

Install `fastboot`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Then simply, reboot to fastboot and do:

```
$ sudo fastboot flash system system.img
```